# Is there an always maximal non-constant function?

Tags: calculus, analysis, special-functions, fixed-point-theorems

I wonder, if there is an function (quite obviously (?) no $\mathbb R$-$\mathbb R$- function) which is non-constant (actually it should be an increasing function) and which is maximal everywhere?
Nice to have (or a necessary condition for the existence for such a function?): The maximum-property may be dependent from an "observer". I am not sure, if this additional condition makes the problem more complex or if this condition may the problem solveable in the first place.

Comment: Taking a stab in the dark here. You could define the function inside a metric space where the distance between any two non-identical points is a non-zero constant (and the distance from a point to itself is zero). Then no matter what value the function has, it's distance from the $x$ axis or $xy$ plane, etc. is the same. Example: the space is a graph, where every node (point) is directly connected to a designated node ("the origin"). The graph would have a star topology (in the sense of a local area network). The distance to the origin is always one, except for the origin itself.

Comment: How about floor($x$)?

Comment: Indeed, I thought of a function with a domain like a circle or the inside of a sphere. The range would be, for instance, just {O}. For refinement I thougt of star-shaped domain.

Comment: @user254665: It is better than nothing, but I would prefer <b>proper</b> maxima.

Comment: It could not be monotonic and have a strict  (proper) local maximum. But for a non-monotonic function, I am sure I have seen this Q here before. And I'm sorry but I  can't recall anything about it.